# Как с помощью js добавить блок напротив другого блока

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть горизонтальный список li и такая функция:

```
$( ".res" ).mouseover(function(event) {

});
```

Как в этой функции создавать блок (или менять его отступы) чтобы он был напротив тега,на который происходит mouseover?

Comment: Что имеется ввиду под словом "напротив" ?

Comment: Справа от блока

Answer (score 0):

Нужно больше конкретики. Попробуй такой вариант:

```
var div = '<div style="margin:5px;display:inline-block">Block</div>';
$('.res').mouseover(function(event) {
    $(this).append(div);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fq1vxp90/23/